# ITL (iTunes Library) Format

Tags: java, itunes, data-formats

I´m developing a Java solution for manage an iTunes Library (ITL file). The ITL format is a propietary one.
I'm looking for an implementation or a documentation about ITL format but Google can't find anything useful.

Does anyone have experience about that? Where to find more information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an open source project called *titl* that sounds exactly what you're looking for.

The repository is here: https://github.com/josephw/titl

Comment: Thanks! it doesn't work 100% with my library, but is a very good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes has an api that you can use to inform iTunes of changes without having to modifying the iTunes ITL file directly. On OSX you can use Applescript, on Windows a DLL that Ive manipulate using Jacob and Java

Answer (score -2):

Most of the time, Apple folks uses preferences list format (or its XML counterpart). As an example, it is the case for iPoho Library file. I have had success parsing this file using [commons configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) in the past. Maybe you could try it.

Comment: iTunes Library have an XML counterpart, as you mentioned. But that file is for information to 3er developers pruporses.
What I want to do is modify the ITL file so iTunes get my changes. For example, change a path of a file, increment the track count indicator, etc...

Comment: Have you had any luck CHiRo79?  I'm 14 and just starting out with programming... would love to do something with my music for final projec!!!

Comment: @user446936 Look at the acceped answer (the one with the green check) regarding the titl library.