# Can I use Applescript to find the current iTunes media location and other iTunes options

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

Can I use Applescript to find the current iTunes media location and other iTunes options.There doesnt seem to be such options when I read the iTunes Applescript Dictionary within Script Editor but surely there is a way to do it.

I read in the past that something is stored in com.itunes.plist but its not plaintext and my plist file did not change when I created a new libary so Im not convinced it is still used, or if it is kept up to date.

Comment: Do you want to reveal the file to song that is playing or do you want to use the folder location in a different way?

Comment: @oa Nothing to do with a song currently playing (if any) I want to know the path of the current media folder location, i.e if I add a new song to iTunes and I have iTunes configured to copy media files where will it copy the file to.

Comment: What 'other iTunes options' are you referring to?

Comment: @NicolasRiley The 'Keep iTunes media folder organized' and the 'Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library' options

Answer (score 2):

Yes, @PaulTaylor, you can get the media folder location of the current user in AppleScript using the Apple-provided ​iTunes​Library framework. (documentation at [iTunesLibrary at Apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/ituneslibrary))

Here's a working AppleScript to do it:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later

use framework "iTunesLibrary"

set lib to current application's ITLibrary's libraryWithAPIVersion:"1.0" |error|:(missing value)

set mediaFolderPath to POSIX path of (lib's mediaFolderLocation as alias)

--> "/Volumes/LaCie 6/iTunes Library/"
```

Comment: Interesting, so am i right in thinking this can also be used to find out what is in the iTunes library without actually starting iTunes as I do with my current applescript code that starts with 'tell application "iTunes"'. I wonder it will be faster, and if it also availble for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The media location is not saved in the global iTunes preference file. Because you can have multiple libraries, and each library defines its own media location, this is actually saved in the the library preferences. The default library is located at `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.itl`. I'm not sure what kind of file this is. It does not seem to be a plist/xml file, nor an sqlite file. It seems to just be a proprietary binary file.

Inside the same folder, I also found `iTunes Music Library.xml` (after some testing around, that file is now missing, so YMMV for the rest of this explanation). Here is a truncated example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>12.3.3.17</string>
    <key>Date</key><date>2016-04-14T19:35:27Z</date>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>1AEAB6C2057C2167</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
    </dict>
    <key>Playlists</key>
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>Music Folder</key><string>file:///Users/<username>/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note the key `Music Folder`. This is the setting you are looking for to find the library's media location. There are also some library settings, such as a list of playlists and track information.

Comment: Unfortunately the iTunes Music Library.xml is now optional depending on user preference 'Share iTunes LIbrary Xml with other Applications' which defaults to false, but thanks anyway I didnt realize it was actually stored in this file. SO it must be stored in the itl file but seems no way to decode it.

Comment: @PaulTaylor According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2888005/2348587) there is a java project on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/titl/) to read .itl files. It sounds like it's not fully developed and would add a lot of extra dependency for you, but it looks like that's the only option available to get the filepath you want.